# Der Unterschied zwischen "verwehren" und "verbieten"

Tags: difference, verb, synonym

Diese zwei Verben sind im Duden ganz ähnlich erklärt:

> **Verbieten:** etwas für nicht erlaubt erklären; etwas zu unterlassen gebieten; untersagen
>
> **Verwehren:** jemandem etwas nicht zu tun erlauben; verweigern

Ist *verwehren* vielleicht gehobener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Verbieten**: *to forbid*
To tell someone that they should not do something. They're still able to do it, though.

> Ich verbiete dir darüber zu reden. (I forbid you to talk about that.)
>   Ich verbiete dir zu gehen. (I forbid you to go/leave.)

*Verbieten* can also be used to express a ban (legal system):

> Die Veröffentlichung des Albums wurde verboten. (The publication of the album was forbidden.)
>   Die Partei wurde verboten. (The party was forbidden.)

**Verwehren**: *to refuse*, *to deny*
You actively prevent someone from doing something. They're not able to do it.

> Man verwehrte uns den Eintritt. (They refused us admission.)
>   Uns wurde der Zugang zu den Daten verwehrt. (Access to the information was denied to us.)

Answer (score 4):

*Verbieten* means to disallow, *verwehren* means to actively prevent you from doing something.

Answer (score 0):

Wie die Erklärung sagen will, ist *verwehren* eigentlich grundsätzlich spezifischer.

> Ich verwehre dir den Zutritt (lasse aber andere hinein)

versus

> Zutritt verboten (d. h. im Prinzip für alle)

Zudem steckt in *verwehren* auch die Abwehr, d. h., ein Verbot spricht man i. Allg. vorab aus, während das Verwehren i. Allg. erst als Maßnahme gegen ein konkretes Begehren / einen konkreten Versuch geschieht (trotzdem durchaus nicht notwendigerweise mit Gewalt).

Comment: "Ich verbiete dir zu gehen, lasse aber alle anderen."

Answer (score 0):

Nimm die Parteien **A, B** und **C** an.
**A** will etwas von **B** nehmen.
**B** verwehrt **A** diesen Wunsch.
**C** verbietet **A** diesen Wunsch. **B** kann allerdings auch verbieten.
Verbieten bedeutet natürlich auch, dass **C** (und **B**) die Autorität dazu hat. Verwehren, dass B stark genug ist, dies zu unterbinden. Oder, dass **A** genügend Respekt vor **B** oder **C** hat und sich an die Ansage hält.